# Error when trying to deploy Google cloud function in Go 1.11 using go modules

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, go-modules

I am having issues trying to deploy a Google cloud function in Go 1.11 using Go modules. I have have the following code structure in my `GOPATH`:

```
└── example
    ├── models
    │   ├── go.mod
    │   └── models.go
    └── load
        ├── fn.go
        ├── go.mod
        ├── go.sum
        └── vendor
            └── ....
```

the load/go.mod looks like the following:

```
module github.com/example/load

require (
    github.com/example/models v0.0.0
)

replace github.com/example/models => ../models
```

When I try to deploy the function using the command

```sh
gcloud functions deploy load-data --entry-point GCSNewFileTrigger --runtime go111 --trigger-resource new_data --trigger-event google.storage.object.finalize
```

I get the following error:

```
Deploying function (may take a while - up to 2 minutes)...failed.                                                                                                                                                                     
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Build failed: go: parsing /models/go.mod: open /models/go.mod: no such file or directory
go: error loading module requirements
```

The commands `go mod vendor` and `go mod verify` run successfully locally and I can see my local package `models` in the vendor folder of `load`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Modules are preferred by the builder over vendor. If there is a `go.mod`, modules will be used. When you upload your function, it only includes the directory with your function at the root, not any directories one level up. So, when there is a `go.mod` and you have a replace directive pointing one level up, it will not work.

The solution is to vendor and not upload the `go.mod`/`go.sum` files. When using `gcloud`, you can create a `.gcloudignore` file to do this for you. See https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/go-runtime#specifying_dependencies for more detail.

Disclaimer: I work at Google and on this product.

Comment: `metadata.FromContext` will fail when using vendor according to [this post](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/issues/1947). Any solutions without vendoring?