# Deploy Google Cloud Function using Go modules and vendoring at the same time

Tags: go, google-cloud-functions, go-modules, vendoring

I am trying to deploy a [Google Cloud Function in Go](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/go-runtime), but got an error while deploying because I use, at the same time, subpackages **and** "internal modules" (only defined on my host, not deployed anywhere). I have the following structure :

```
.
├── function
│   ├── package1
│   │   └── file1.go
│   ├── function.go
│   ├── go.mod
│   └── go.sum
└── common
    ├── common.go
    ├── go.mod
    └── go.sum
```

Contents of my `function.go` (entrypoint of my Cloud Function) :

```
package function

import (
    "github.com/.../function/package1"
    "github.com/.../common"
)

// use functions from package1 and common
```

Topics have been covered individually here :

- [Error when trying to deploy Google cloud function in Go 1.11 using go modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54410963/error-when-trying-to-deploy-google-cloud-function-in-go-1-11-using-go-modules)
- [How can I use a sub-packages with Go on Google Cloud Functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54255485/how-can-i-use-a-sub-packages-with-go-on-google-cloud-functions)

The first post indicates to use vendoring and exclude `go.mod` and `go.sum` from the source to be able to use `common` module, while the 2nd indicates to include `go.mod` and `go.sum` without vendoring to be able to use subpackages.

But I am wondering : is it possible to use both at the same time? Or vendoring dependencies requires to put all `.go` source files in the same directory (no subpackages)? Likewise, using subpackages requires to not use vendoring? How can I structure my code to avoid those restrictions, or what can I do (deploy `common` module somewhere, ...)?

Also, the [documentation on "Specifying dependencies" for Go Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-go) states that :

> Cloud Functions in Go must provide all of their dependencies via **either** Go modules with a go.mod file, or a vendor directory. Your function **cannot specify dependencies using both** Go modules and a vendor directory at the same time.

Comment: You can absolutely use vendoring with multiple packages. Pretty much any non-throwaway project (so, anything that would be inclined to vendor dependencies) will be made up of multiple packages, so this is the typical use case.

Comment: Are you sure you need the inner package defined as its own module?

Comment: @Adrian This module is used by other cloud functions, so to avoid code duplication, it should be defined in a separated module. Are you sure about your assumption `You can absolutely use vendoring with multiple packages` when applied to Google Cloud Functions? In Go (in general), I agree with you, but here it does not seem possible.

Comment: Code re-use is a good reason to have it in a separate *package*, not a separate module. Modules can contain multiple packages. It's only necessary to declare them as separate *modules* if you need to maintain separate module versions for each: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#faqs--multi-module-repositories or if they are truly, completely distinct (but in that case they would typically be in separate repositories).

Comment: So if I understand correctly, I should have created a single *module*, and define `function` and `common` as *packages*? If this is correct, I don't think it fits Google Cloud Function deployment model (https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-go).

Comment: I don't see anything on that page suggesting that you can't deploy a module containing multiple packages. I'd be extremely surprised if that was a constraint, given that 99% of modules (and programs) contain multiple packages.

Comment: There are multiple constraints concerning code structure to deploy a Cloud Function in Go (see the docs : https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/#functions-writing-file-structuring-go). As for the usage of packages, it's stated in this doc : `Note: You must use Go modules, by providing a go.mod file, to use sub-packages.`. Packaging in the context of Cloud Functions can be somewhat different of "classical" packaging in Go, that's why it brings confusion.

Comment: The second bullet on that page shows an example of a package and sub-package with only the outer package having a go.mod file.

Comment: Yes, it's the upper part of the hierarchy shown in my question. But there is no other directory **at the same level** as `function/`, like I've presented. This topic is also covered by this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54255485/how-can-i-use-a-sub-packages-with-go-on-google-cloud-functions I provided in my question. But I'm afraid that is not the point I'm addressing.

Comment: If you have any experience in deploying Cloud Functions in Go, could you please write a simple example showing how to deploy a Cloud Function, based on the code structure I provided? Remembering that `common` should be separated because code inside is used by other Functions (located at the same level as `function/`). That would be very helpful because I think there is a misunderstanding between us.