# How to run a Google Cloud Function using Go with dependencies in private repositories?

Tags: git, go, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to adapt the Go example from this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/pubsub) to something that uses dependencies in a private repository. Here is the Cloud Function sample code:

```golang
package helloworld

import (
    "context"
    "log"

    "github.com/kurtpeek/my-private-repo/mypackage"
)

// PubSubMessage is the payload of a Pub/Sub event.
type PubSubMessage struct {
    Data []byte `json:"data"`
}

// HelloPubSub2 consumes a Pub/Sub message.
func HelloPubSub2(ctx context.Context, m PubSubMessage) error {
    name := string(m.Data)
    if name == "" {
        name = "World"
    }
    log.Printf("Hello, %s!", name)
    log.Println(mypackage.SayHello())
    return nil
}
```

where `SayHello()` is defined in the private repo `github.com/kurtpeek/my-private-repo` as

```golang
package mypackage

// SayHello says hello
func SayHello() string {
    return "Hello, world!"
}
```

Without the invocation of `mypackage.SayHello()`, the Cloud Function deploys and runs as expected. I'm also able to run `HelloPubSub2` in a `main.go` after running

```
git config url."git@github.com".insteadOf "https://github.com"
```

and adding my SSH key to the repo (cf. this [Medium article](https://medium.com/cloud-native-the-gathering/go-modules-with-private-git-repositories-dfe795068db4)).

However, if I try it with the `mypackage.SayHello()`, I get the following error:

> could not read Username for 'https://github.com'

Here is the full terminal output:

```
> 
gcloud functions deploy HelloPubSub2 --runtime go113 --trigger-topic mytopic
Created .gcloudignore file. See `gcloud topic gcloudignore` for details.
WARNING: Function created with limited-access IAM policy. To enable unauthorized access consider "gcloud alpha functions add-iam-policy-binding HelloPubSub2 --member=allUsers --role=roles/cloudfunctions.invoker"
Deploying function (may take a while - up to 2 minutes)...failed.                                              
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Build failed: {"error":{"buildpackId":"google.go.functions-framework","buildpackVersion":"0.9.0","errorType":13,"canonicalCode":13,"errorId":"03a1e2f7","errorMessage":"go: github.com/kurtpeek/my-private-repo@v0.0.0-20200508055124-8eb94cb388b2: invalid version: git fetch -f origin refs/heads/*:refs/heads/* refs/tags/*:refs/tags/* in /layers/google.go.functions-framework/functions-framework/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/93c0b37d34e5cf0f9b9778b99e5968bf272c89cabd21f8c0d683212c8dd2ef89: exit status 128:\n\tfatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled"},"stats":null}
```

What is the best way to deploy this Cloud Function? Should I run `go mod vendor` and then change the dependencies to reference the `vendor/` directory? (This seems like a hassle to do every time, though).

### Update

This documentation, https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-go#using_private_dependencies, addresses exactly this use case. I wasn't quite able to get it to work yet, though. I've added

```
go.mod
go.sum
```

to my `.gcloudignore` and ran `go mod vendor`, thereby creating a `vendor/` directory, but if I try to deploy it again, I now get

> cannot find package \"github.com/kurtpeek/my-private-repo/mypackage\" in any of:\n\t/usr/local/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/my-private-repo/mypackage (from $GOROOT)\n\t/workspace/src/github.com/kurtpeek/my-private-repo/mypackage (from $GOPATH)"

```
~/g/s/g/k/m/helloworld> 
gcloud functions deploy HelloPubSub2 --runtime go113 --trigger-topic mytopic
Deploying function (may take a while - up to 2 minutes)...failed.                                            
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Build failed: {"error":{"buildpackId":"google.go.build","buildpackVersion":"0.9.0","errorType":2,"canonicalCode":2,"errorId":"6191efcd","errorMessage":"src/helloworld/helloworld.go:7:2: cannot find package \"github.com/kurtpeek/my-private-repo/mypackage\" in any of:\n\t/usr/local/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/my-private-repo/mypackage (from $GOROOT)\n\t/workspace/src/github.com/kurtpeek/my-private-repo/mypackage (from $GOPATH)"},"stats":null}
```

I'm running this inside my `GOPATH`:

```
kurt@Kurts-MacBook-Pro-13 ~/g/s/g/k/my-cloud-function> go env GOPATH
/Users/kurt/go
kurt@Kurts-MacBook-Pro-13 ~/g/s/g/k/my-cloud-function> pwd
/Users/kurt/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/my-cloud-function
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Are you using  `Docker`? Docker can help build a container including all the dependencies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came across the answer (by a Google engineer working on this product) [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/issues/743#issuecomment-458574149) as well as in [Error when trying to deploy Google cloud function in Go 1.11 using go modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54410963/error-when-trying-to-deploy-google-cloud-function-in-go-1-11-using-go-modules). The key point is that `gcloud functions deploy` only copies the contents of the directory in which it is run into the Cloud Function's 'context', so the `vendor/` directory has to be in that directory. At the same time, I noticed that the `package` cannot be `main`, so I took the somewhat unusual step of removing the `go.mod` from the repo's root directory and running `go mod init` and `go mod vendor` in the `helloworld` directory. Now it works:

```
> 
gcloud functions deploy HelloPubSub2 --runtime go113 --trigger-topic mytopic
Deploying function (may take a while - up to 2 minutes)...done.                                                         
availableMemoryMb: 256
entryPoint: HelloPubSub2
eventTrigger:
...
```

Comment: I found out that you can also specify to exclude modules files in the .gcloudignore file, instead of removing those files.